# Flex Mobile Item Renderer in List

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex-mobile

I use an item renderer in flex mobile List component, item renderer have to display different images row by row according to received input data. I do these all controls in creationComplete of item renderer so that if its "X" make the source of image this one etc. But when I scroll it after List is created it resettles items but in different order, so that if "Item1" is on the first row of List after scrolling it goes to the last row and the last row comes to first place.

List component code:

```
<s:List id="lst" dataProvider="{dp}" width="100%" height="100%" 
        itemRenderer="renderer.YataklarViewRenderer"
        contentBackgroundAlpha="0" borderColor="#FFFFFF" borderVisible="true" >

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout 
            horizontalAlign="center" 
            paddingBottom="10"
            paddingTop="10"
            paddingLeft="10"
            paddingRight="10"
            />
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Item Renderer code:

```
protected function yataklarItem_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                trace("Creation complete: "+ data['servisAdi']);    


                var servisAdi:String = data['servisAdi'];

                //header text ekle
                this.addElement(header);
                header_text.text = servisAdi;


                var odalar:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

                odalar = data['odalar'];

                for(var i:int=0;i<odalar.length;i++){



                    var mainContent:VGroup = new VGroup();
                    //                  mainContent.paddingBottom
                    mainContent.percentWidth = 100;
                    mainContent.percentWidth = 100;
                    mainContent.horizontalAlign = "center";
                    mainContent.verticalAlign = "middle";


                    var hContent:HGroup = new HGroup();
                    hContent.percentWidth = 100;
                    hContent.verticalAlign = "middle";
                    hContent.horizontalAlign = "left";


                    var col1:HGroup = new HGroup();
                    col1.percentWidth = 10;
                    col1.verticalAlign = "middle";
                    col1.horizontalAlign = "center";

                    var col2:HGroup = new HGroup();
                    col2.percentWidth = 20;
                    col2.verticalAlign = "middle";
                    col2.horizontalAlign = "center";


                    var imgCol:Image = new Image();
                    var txtOdaAdi:Label = new Label();

                    var oda:Object = new Object();
                    oda = odalar.getItemAt(i);

                    var odaAdi:String = oda['odaAdi'];
                    var baskinCinsiyyet:String = oda['baskinCinsiyet'];

                    txtOdaAdi.text = odaAdi;
                    imgCol.source = "images/yataklar/baskin"+baskinCinsiyyet+".png";

                    col1.addElement(imgCol);
                    col2.addElement(txtOdaAdi);


                    var ytk:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                    ytk = oda['yataklar'];

                    var yataklarCol:HGroup = new HGroup();
                    yataklarCol.percentWidth = 70;
                    yataklarCol.horizontalAlign = "left";
                    yataklarCol.verticalAlign = "center";


                    for( var j:int=0;j<ytk.length;j++){

                        var yatakG:VGroup = new VGroup();
                        yatakG.gap = 5;
                        yatakG.horizontalAlign = "center";
                        yatakG.verticalAlign = "middle";

                        var yatak:Object = new Object();
                        yatak = ytk.getItemAt(j);

                        var yatakNo:int = yatak['yatakNo'];
                        var durumu:String = yatak['durumu'];

                        //uzerine tiklandiginda
                        var vizitId:String = yatak['vizitId'];
                        var hastaId:String = yatak['hastaId'];
                        var adiSoyadi:String = yatak['adiSoyadi'];


                        var txtYatakNo:Label = new Label();
                        txtYatakNo.text = yatakNo.toString();

                        var imgYatakImg:Image = new Image();
                        imgYatakImg.source = "images/yataklar/yatak"+durumu+".png";

                        yatakG.addElement(imgYatakImg);
                        yatakG.addElement(txtYatakNo);


                        yataklarCol.addElement(yatakG);
                    }


                    hContent.addElement(col1);
                    hContent.addElement(col2);
                    hContent.addElement(yataklarCol);

                    mainContent.addElement(hContent);
                    mainContent.addElement(line);

                    this.addElement(mainContent);
                }




            }
<fx:Declarations>


        <s:Group id="header" width="100%" height="50">

            <s:Rect 
                width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                        <s:GradientEntry color="0x314F83" />
                    </s:LinearGradient>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>

            <s:VGroup id="vgt" paddingBottom="10" paddingTop="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" gap="10" width="100%" 
                      verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="left" height="100%">
                <s:Label id="header_text" color="#FFFFFF" verticalAlign="middle" height="100%"/> 
            </s:VGroup>

        </s:Group>


        <s:Line id="line" width="100%">
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x5b5b5b" weight="2"/>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Line>






    </fx:Declarations>


    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout verticalAlign="top" horizontalAlign="center" />       
    </s:layout>
```

I think everything is correct in my codes but I have to add some extra lines. Can anybody help me with that tricky line?

Answer (score 1):

> do these all controls in creationComplete of item renderer so that if
>   its "X" make the source of image this one etc.

That's a problem.  A Flex List only renders what is shown on screen, they do not render what is off screen.  When you scroll the renderer is re-used, new renderers are not created.  The creationComplete event will not be fired again to update the render for the data that is being displayed.

The process of reusing renderers is called Renderer recycling.  To properly create a renderer, you must listen for the dataChange event to tweak the renderers display based on the data.

Some people prefer to override the set data method in the itemRenderer and make their changes there.  This is also an equally acceptable approach.

The reason setting useVirtualLayout to false worked is because that tells the list to render every item separately without making use of renderer recycling.  This is not the best choice for performance or memory usage reasons on mobile.

[Please read the docs on using the data property in itemRenderers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS77c1dbb1bd80d3836ecbb5ec129ec77b1e1-8000.html#WSdfd41de286dc919d-63248ba71211ccd7b7c-7fff).

Comment: I have tried the same by overriding set data method but there was a mess when I scrolled.. Can you give an example on using dataChange?!

Comment: @lbstr Since you didn't show your full itemRenderer, just snippets of it; I decided not to try to rewrite it to use the dataChange() method.  If you can elaborate on what "a mess" means; I may be able to offer other assistance.

Comment: in set data case, when I scroll the list it regenerates new item instances.. and resettles them in different places as well..

Comment: @lbstr Ugh, I see now.  You're creating a lot of children in creationComplete.  Please read up on the Flex Component LifeCycle at: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html and here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf68641-7ff0.html .  You're children should be created in createChildren(); and then sized and positioned in updateDisplayList() . When I mix MXML created Children and ActionScript created Children; it always ends badly.  You should switch to one approach or the other.

Comment: I don't think that it causes because of the number of children I create. And also if you take a look at my creation complete then you can see that all components are created in ActionScript, there're only unnecessary ones in declarations. Btw I didn't understand your createChildren() & updateDisplayList(), can you give a little example, its not necessary to be on my code... just a few lines of code will be enough..

Comment: @lbstr Read the two links I linked to.  Here is some more info I wrote on creating mobile itemRenderers: https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/6/23/Understanding-Mobile-itemRenderers and https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/6/24/Building-a-Mobile-ItemRenderer-in-Flex .  The second link has code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<s:List useVirtualLayout="false">` solved the problem for me!

Comment: -1... while I have no doubt this works; it is not the best approach for performance or memory usage reasons, and those two things are important especially on mobile devices.  The proper way to write a renderer is to listen for the dataChange event.  See my answer for more details.